# How do I find the derivative of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Find the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ if:

$$y=\int_0^{\ln(8x)}\sin (5e^t)\, dt$$
I don't understand how to approach this question as it has $\sin$ and exponentials combined.

Comment: Use the chain rule + fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: Always remember to pay respect to eggs

Comment: Why with respect to eggs? Why not!

Comment: @Mathematician Note that users are expected to provide context for their questions, [as is explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would help if you could answer any of the following: what are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Where did you encounter this problem? Are there any facts that you recently covered in you course/textbook that you think could be relevant here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the fundamental theorem of calculus, there is no need to do anything special with the "combination of sin and e". We can write $y$ in the form
$$
y = F(\ln(8x)) - F(0),
$$
where $F$ is a function for which $\frac{dF}{dx} = \sin(5e^x)$ (we don't have to say what the function $F$ "really is"). Using the chain rule, find $\frac{dy}{dx}$:
$$
\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {d}{dx} [F(\ln(8x))] = \sin[5e^{[\ln(8x)]}] \cdot \frac{d}{dx} \ln(8x)
\\ = \sin[5 (8x)] \cdot \frac 1{x} = \frac{\sin(40x)}{x}.
$$

Comment: @Mathematician I'm not sure how you ended up with that answer. No, that is not correct, I've added a complete solution

Comment: @Mathematician I see now that you have taken the derivative of $\frac{dy}{dx}$, but I don't see why you have done this

Comment: I understand now thanks